# Limit the number of running instances of a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script, say scriptB that needs to be run 1000 times, getting called from another script, say scriptA. How can I make sure that there are no more than n running instances of the scriptB? I need to make the entire process faster, so I need to have parallelism.

Comment: We need some more information about your problem domain before we can give great advice, but this might start you in the right direction, and you might then be able to write your own answer and accept it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: if you have 4 processes give each one 250 tasks.
if you have 2 processes then each should do 500 ... the process its self should not have to worry about that ... the caller should

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thats alright, in cases I need at max 10 instances of scriptB running at a given time, do you mean to say I will need to create 10 processes?

Comment: yes ... but you probably dont want more processes than you have cores ... (Ie it would be faster to have 4 processes on a 4 core chip and have each process do 3 jobs, than it would be to have 12 processes each do 1 job)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Depends on what the processes are doing and how much they are sleeping (e.g. if they are doing disk or network i/o).

Comment: @augurar fair enough ... but as a general rule of thumb ... not necessarily always true, but mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import scriptB's function into scriptA. I'm assuming scriptA is also a python script.

scriptB

```
def scriptB_function(x):
  return x*x
```

scriptA

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from scriptB import scriptB_function

args = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

pool = ThreadPool(4) # 4 threads in pool
result = pool.map(scriptB_function, args)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: I have a minor gripe in calling it ThreadPool ... since its not threaded ... its multiprocessing ... but its nit picky ... +1 all the same

Comment: Thanks. Helps me getting started.

Comment: depending on your processor and your script (hyperthreading etc.) the optimal thread count can be up to 2x your number of cores.